# How to get function pointer in LLVM

Tags: c, compiler-construction, pthreads, llvm, llvm-ir

I need to insert `IR` instruction to call pthread_create in my `LoopPass`, so I need to pass the actual function as an argument that `pthread_create` is supposed to call on the new thread.

Currently I have defined the function to run on the new thread as

```
Function *worker_func = Function::Create(funcType,
                                      GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage,
                                      "worker_func",
                                      CurrentModule);
```

And I got the pointer to `pthread_create` by the following:

```
Function *func_pthread_create = dyn_cast<Function>(
    TheModule->getOrInsertFunction("pthread_create", pthreadCreateTy));
```

And I need to pass an array of `Type*` as the arguments to `pthread_create` like below.

```
Value* pthread_create_call = builder.CreateCall(
    func_pthread_create, args, "pthread_create");
```

with the args as:

```
Value* args[4];
args[0] = pthread_t_ld
args[1] = llvm::Constant::getNullValue(llvm::Type::getInt8Ty(getGlobalContext())->getPointerTo());

args[2] = ??? // supposed to be the pointer to worker_func`

args[3] = llvm::Constant::getNullValue(llvm::Type::getInt8Ty(getGlobalContext())->getPointerTo());
```

So how can I get the pointer to this `worker_func` function to pass into `pthread_create`?

Comment: Backticks `\`` are for inline code.  Indent four spaces for blocks of code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to bitcast `func_pthread_create` to the type the function expects and pass the result of that bitcast as the 3rd argument. You can use the static `ConstantExpr::getBitCast` method for that, passing it the function as the first argument and the type of the third parameter of `func_pthread_create` as the second argument.